# Websphere 85 ejb 3 deploy issue

Tags: java, ejb-3.0, websphere-8, ejb-jar.xml

I am trying to deploy a bean that is ejb 3 on websphere 8. Bean implementation is in src/main/java and ejb-jar.xml is in src/main/resources/META-INF.
This is packaged in a jar and the jar is included in ear that also has other ejb jar with ejb 2.
So ear contains both ejb 2 and ejb 3 jars.
During deployment of this ear in websphere, I am getting below error:

**org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ejb-jar'.**

If I remove ejb-jar.xml from ejb 3 jar, deployment is successful.
If I deploy an ear containing only ejb 3 jar, it is successful.
If I deploy ejb 3 jar directly from ibm console, it gets deployed successfully.

But trying to deploy an ear containing both ejb 2 and ejb 3 jar is failing. Below is full stacktrace:

```
 [echo] Error executing deployment: org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException. Error is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ejb-jar'..
 [echo] org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ejb-jar'.
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMRenderer.loadDocument(EMF2DOMRenderer.java:81)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMRenderer.doLoad(EMF2DOMRenderer.java:62)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.TranslatorResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(TranslatorResourceImpl.java:153)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.doLoad(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:182)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1494)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceImpl.load(ResourceImpl.java:1282)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.load(CompatibilityXMIResourceImpl.java:272)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.TranslatorResourceImpl.load(TranslatorResourceImpl.java:423)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ResourceSetImpl.java:255)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.jem.internal.util.emf.workbench.ProjectResourceSetImpl.demandLoad(ProjectResourceSetImpl.java:815)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.demandLoadHelper(ResourceSetImpl.java:270)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.jem.internal.util.emf.workbench.ProjectResourceSetImpl.getResource(ProjectResourceSetImpl.java:1068)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.WorkbenchResourceHelper.getOrCreateResource(WorkbenchResourceHelper.java:380)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emfworkbench.integration.EditModel.getResource(EditModel.java:685)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.componentcore.internal.ArtifactEditModel.getResource(ArtifactEditModel.java:199)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.componentcore.util.EJBArtifactEdit.getDeploymentDescriptorResource(EJBArtifactEdit.java:296)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.componentcore.util.EJBArtifactEdit.getDeploymentDescriptorRoot(EJBArtifactEdit.java:322)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.componentcore.util.EJBArtifactEdit.getEJBJar(EJBArtifactEdit.java:306)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.componentcore.util.EJBArtifactEdit.getEJBClientJarModule(EJBArtifactEdit.java:252)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.jst.j2ee.ejb.internal.plugin.EjbModuleExtensionImpl.getDefinedEJBClientJARProject(EjbModuleExtensionImpl.java:91)
 [echo]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.runEarDeploy(BatchExtension.java:482)
 [echo]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension$RunDeploy.run(BatchExtension.java:356)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1975)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:1957)
 [echo]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension$RunDeploy.execute(BatchExtension.java:321)
 [echo]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.plugin.BatchExtension.run(BatchExtension.java:284)
 [echo]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [echo]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
 [echo]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
 [echo]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.callMethodWithException(EclipseAppContainer.java:587)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:198)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
 [echo]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 [echo]     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
 [echo]     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
 [echo]     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
 [echo]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BootLoaderLoader.run(BootLoaderLoader.java:494)
 [echo]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.batch.impl.BatchDeploy.execute(BatchDeploy.java:114)
 [echo]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.execute(EJBDeploy.java:106)
 [echo]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.deploy(EJBDeploy.java:348)
 [echo]     at com.ibm.etools.ejbdeploy.EJBDeploy.main(EJBDeploy.java:309)
 [echo] Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'ejb-jar'.
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleStartElement(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl$NSContentDispatcher.scanRootElementHook(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(Unknown Source)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.utilities.DOMUtilities.loadDocument(DOMUtilities.java:554)
 [echo]     at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2DOMRenderer.loadDocument(EMF2DOMRenderer.java:74)
 [echo]     ... 43 more
 [echo] EJBDeploy level: @build@
```

**ejb-jar.xml**
`<ejb-jar xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
    <display-name></display-name>
    <enterprise-beans>
        <session id="">
            <description><![CDATA[]]></description>
            <ejb-name></ejb-name>
            <env-entry>
                <env-entry-name></env-entry-name>
                <env-entry-type></env-entry-type>
                <env-entry-value><![CDATA[]]></env-entry-value>
            </env-entry>`

I believe deployment is failing because ear has both ejb 2 and ejb 2 jars.

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: just to be clear, you don't have `src/main/java/` or `src/main/resources` in your ear do you?

Comment: Correct. EJB is packaged in jar. and jar content looks like:  com/.../.../*.java..           META-INF/ejb-jar.xml

Comment: According to [this](https://community.oracle.com/thread/972695?tstart=0) Oracle's community thread you can mix both EJB2.x and EJB3.x as long as the EJB's are in separate modules. Furthermore, refer to [this](https://docs.jboss.org/ejb3/docs/tutorial/1.0.7/html/EJB2.1_and_EJB3_references.html) JBoss document in order to validate your `ejb-jar.xml` DTD references.

Comment: Does the EAR containing the EJB 2 JAR only deploy successfully?  I suspect one or the other EJB JARs has a malformed ejb-jar.xml.  If you can show the first few lines of each of the ejb-jar.xml, perhaps someone here can identify the issue (the xmlns and DOCTYPE requirements change with each release, so perhaps there is a mistake).  Otherwise, you could consider opening a PMR with IBM; the error message should be improved to at least include more context.

Comment: I updated question with ejb-jar.xml content above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your XML header is using incompatible `xmlns` and `version` attributes.  Try this:

```
<ejb-jar version="3.0"
      xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/ejb-jar_3_0.xsd">
```

(Your EJB 2.x ejb-jar.xml might also have a mismatch, so showing that might also be useful.)

Comment: Thanks Brett.. Below is ejb 2 ejb-jar.xml:

`<ejb-jar id="" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/ejb-jar_2_1.xsd" version="2.1">

   <description>></description>
   <display-name></display-name>

   <enterprise-beans>
      <session id="">
         <description></description>

         <ejb-name></ejb-name>

         <home></home>
         <remote></remote>
         <ejb-class></ejb-class>`

Comment: I changed the namespace and now it gives below exception:          
   `Error executing deployment:     org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException. Error is     org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file..
  org.eclipse.emf.common.util.WrappedException: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Premature end of file.
   at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.EMF2SAXRenderer.doLoad(EMF2SAXRenderer.java:100)
   at org.eclipse.wst.common.internal.emf.resource.TranslatorResourceImpl.basicDoLoad(TranslatorResourceImpl.java:153)
`

Comment: Ignore above. I removed some of the new line characters from xml and it got deployed. Thanks a lot Brett.

Comment: Hi Vaidehi, I think I hit a similar problem. you said you removed some of the new lione characters from the xml, from where? Thanks.